# what falls under the circumstances of accidental drinking water during wudu? no

Tags: sawm, ramadan

what counts as accidental drinking water during wudu while fasting? because i put a little bit of water at the front of my mouth and i think i let the water drop out of my mouth (not 100 percent sure) then midway during wudu i swallowed i didn’t spit it out because i always do it at the end (my body like force swallowed) and some water may have went down but i’m not 100 percent sure should i continue fasting or break it?

Answer (score 1):

If you do anything unintentionally or accidentally then there is no sin for that. But do try to be careful the next time.

Prophet Muhammad (SAWW) once said, ***"The reward of deeds depends upon the intention and every person will get the reward according to  what he has intended."***

Answer (score 0):

Salam aleykoum,

What you describe is accidental so you can continue to fast normally.
May Allah accept our fasts

Comment: thanks you very much